# Borderlands 2 op leveling

Tags: borderlands-2

I have a level 53 commando on borderlands 2 and i was wondering wether I could get an op level, and continue leveling my characters regular levels. I would like to know before i run the risk of messing up my character.

Comment: What's an OP level?

Comment: OverPower level.  It makes the enemies stronger (and drop better gear).
I think of it as leveling (so enemies and items scale) but without the skill points.

Answer (score 1):

OP levels can only be done after Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode, and only change the level of loot that drops, OP-level loot you can equip, and enemies. Your character level is not changed. I'm not 100% sure about this, but I'm almost certain that the completion of Digistruct Peak will not unlock OP levels until you are level 72.